# @media keeps getting parse errors. The errors are according to the validator on line 136 and 196,

Tags: css

According to the validator the errors are at line 136 and line 196.

I have tried to remove and change the font-size, because `vW` isn't a valid font-size, but that didn't change anything.

I hope you can figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) {

    .navbar {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #BA6815;
    position: static; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 51%; 
    height: 50%;
    }

    .tabletfoto img {
        display: inline;
        float: right;
        width: 51%;
    }

    .titel {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 4.5vw;
        color: #001111;
    }

    .titelnavbar {
        text-align: center;
        color: #001111;
        font-size: 5.5vw;
    }
    .normaletekst {
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 3vw;
    }

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) { 

    .tabletfoto img {
        display: none;
    }


    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #BA6815;
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0; 
        max-width: 14%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15% 13%;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.5vw;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
        color: #AA0000;
        font-size: 2vw;
    }


    .titel {
        text-align: center;
        color: #2E2A27;
        font-size: 2.5vw;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .titelnavbar {
        text-align: center;
        color: #2E2A27;
        font-size: 2.5vw;
    }



    .normaletekst {
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
        margin-left: 15%;
        font-size: 2vw;
    }
}
```

Underneath here the error I keep getting:

[image]

Comment: Can you share code relevant only to the specified lines? It's hard for us to count to 136 and then 196...

Comment: @Paulie_D I can't view the images. And don't ask why :). What does the picture show? If it is code, the image is useless, it might be removed.

Comment: Edited to show image

Answer (score 0):

### `vw` is valid as a font-size but the validator isn't up to date.

Note the CSS version it's using is 2.1 which is very old.

**If it works, ignore it**  - unless you are trying to support browsers which do not support anything after 2.1. In that case, use a fallback font-size.

Comment: Thans you so much, I will try another validator as soon as I get home.